# Trying to understand how to initialize ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

**NewAdViewModel**

```
public class NewAdViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
 
    public NewAdViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void loadCategories() {
        //...
    }

}
```

What is the difference between this?

```
NewAdViewModel newAdViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(NewAdViewModel.class);
newAdViewModel.loadCategories();
```

And this?

```
NewAdViewModel newAdViewModel = new NewAdViewModel(requireActivity().getApplication());
newAdViewModel.loadCategories();
```

What is the difference? I'm new with ViewModel

Comment: Please go through [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni Where exactly?

Comment: Essentially, the first creates a viewmodel in a way that allows other components to access the same instance, whereas the second just creates one on the fly and doesn't do any of the setup/config necessary to make it accessible to anyone else (including the Android framework itself).